# Kubuntu 18. Python: starting over completely

Tags: apt, kubuntu, python

In trying to get Octoprint to function, I've been mucking about with python versions and symlinks, and I'd like to start over from Kubuntu's base python install:

- remove all 'python' symlinks (unfortunately, I can't remember what specifically I created)
- remove virtualenv
- remove pip
- remove python (all versions)
- re-install python as it would have been at first Ubuntu load.

Because I'm certain the end goal is going to take a few iterations, a script I could run at will would be great: I'd like to do all this without wiping the HDD and re-installing Kubuntu - though I can if that's what it takes. I'm not a complete newbie to linux but still fumbling around in the dark most of the time, so how do I go about this?

Comment: Beware re-installing Python. Apt depends upon Python, so it's possible to drive yourself off a cliff there. Kubuntu 18 uses Python 2.7.15~rc1 and 3.6.7-1. Don't remove those. Consider running a slightly older version of OctoPrint that is compatible with Py3.6. Alternately, OctoPrint is available [as a Snap](https://snapcraft.io/octoprint-pfs)

Comment: @user535733 So I have learned. Thankfully, ubuntu is easy to start over.